# British airways refund

Tags: bookings, cancellations, british-airways

I booked a flight from MAA to LHR direct flight for travel in January. BA kept cancelling the flight and finally I changed the booking to a connection flight (MAA -> BOM -> LHR) for the 28th of April via another airline.

since the change was initiated by me, BA asked for a hefty sum. So when talking with the BA call center support over the phone on 10 April I asked for the full cancellation and refund.

The representative confirmed he will cancel and refund in a few days. However after a few days, the refund did not come through and now the booking reference says "Sorry, we are unable to display your booking as all the flights have been flown."

Is there a way to get my refund now?

Comment: Your question isn’t clear to me. Which flight are you seeking a refund for - the original BA booking or the new connection flight with another airline?  If you changed the former for the latter, why do you think BA owes you a refund?

Comment: You're not telling us the whole story. They canceled your flight.  They did not schedule you onto another future BA flight.  Right?  Then you had this mystery balance on account and you called up and tried to use it for flights by a different airline, but couldn't make a deal so the change didn't happen.   Change from what?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I should have been more clear. Original direct flight was canceled. I asked BA to rebook in a connecting flight. The connecting flight was in partnership with Vistara; BA would book with Vistara on my behalf for MAA to BOM (this also comes up in BA site) and then BOM to LHR via BA. For the Vistara flight BA asked a lot of money, so I canceled the entire journey with BA.